# Install Mageplaza extension for magento for adding webhook on lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-lightsail

A magento instance is create using amazon lightsail. To add a webhook the following steps must be followed.

```
Magento Admin, choose Store > Settings > Configuration > Mageplaza Extensions > Webhook
```

But **Mageplaza** extension is not installed by default.
So how to continue with this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to lightsail Magento instance using ssh
2. Change to directory to the magento source

   ```bash
   cd /opt/bitnami/magento
   ```
3. use this to install mageplaza webhook

   ```bash
   composer require mageplaza/module-webhook
   ```
4. This is will ask you for username and password

   - Go to [Access Keys](https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/) page and Create A New Access Key.
   - It should look something like this

   ```
    Public Key: c7af7eec85ed51bfc9866c9352e933af
    Private Key: 1bfb1f6873e9ddc1e1b72ea5f0b22b53
   ```

   - `Public Key` is the username
   - `Private Key` is the password
5. Once Installion is done, Do the upgrade

   ```bash
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
6. Compile the latest

   ```bash
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```
7. Lastly deploy the latest

   ```bash
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```

---

Comment: you can change directory to `/bitnami/magento` also